# How to show that number has incremented in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, watir, rubymine

I have code that when I click a button the number increases, and I want to make sure that the number has increased, I'm able to see that the value has changed, but can't show that it's incremented by 1. Here's the code;

```
When(/^I click the create room button$/) do
  createpress = @browser.iframe(:id , 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').button(:id , 'create_room_form_button')
  list = @browser.iframe(:id , 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').div(:id , 'room_list')
  rooms = []

  list.as.each do | room |
    rooms << room.attribute_value('data-room-id')
  end

  roomvalue = rooms.size.to_i
  puts roomvalue

  Watir::Wait.for_condition(10 , 2 , "Waiting for button to be present") {
    createpress.present?
  }
  createpress.click
end

Then(/^the lobby will update to show the new room$/) do
  list = @browser.iframe(:id , 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').div(:id , 'room_list')
  rooms = []

  list.as.each do | room |
    rooms << room.attribute_value('data-room-id')
  end

  puts rooms.size.to_i
end
```

I'm just not sure how to get the 2 outputs to show the information I'm looking for (increment by 1)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, and your test has no assertions. Are you unsure how to write an assertion? Or, is the output from `puts` not what you expect?

Comment: Essentially I want my test to fail if my then statements output isn't 1 increment higher than my when statement

Comment: @JaredBeck is right that you need some kind of assertion. Just calling `puts rooms.size` will result in a `nil` value. While `rooms.size` is not nil, the expression results in it. (You can see this in IRB when you call `puts 'Hello world!'`. It will output the string, followed by `=> nil`) Also, FWIW, you do not need to call `to_i` on `sizes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set an instance value to hold your room size from step to step. (Note: in ruby-Cucumber everything runs inside of World, so that is the object on which you set an instance variable and your World persists across stepdefs).

As a bonus you can use rspec's expectations gem to provide a more natural english way to write the code.

```
When(/^I click the create room button$/) do
  ..snip..
  @current_rooms = rooms
  ..snip..
end

Then(/^the lobby will update to show the new room$/) do
  ..snip..
  updated_room_list = rooms
  updated_room_list.should have(@current_rooms.size + 1).rooms
  ..snip..
end
```

Here is info on [rspec's collection.should have](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-2/docs/matchers/have-n-items-matcher)

NOTE: Your test could run into problems if you ever run your test suite in parallel and have other tests that are adding or deleting rooms. It might be better to make sure the new room's name appears in the list and that the count of rooms is correct, instead of checking that there is one more room than last time.